# Does TMG Reporting hate the month of July?

Tags: reporting, microsoft-ftmg-2010

We have a ForeFront TMG 2010 SP1 installation. Reporting in the past has worked great.

However, I now need to find out why we've ripped through half our monthly quota in the first 6 days of the billing cycle, and TMG is failing me. The reports are generating OK, but there's just no data in them.

I can report just fine right up until the 1st of July. Any reports from the 1st of July just come back with no data.

I checked the logs inside MSDE and as far as I can tell the SQL data is all intact, but I know that TMG compiles these statistics nightly and stores them somewhere, but I can't find where to verify if they are working correctly.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot reporting in TMG 2010?

Comment: You Aussies and your quotas...I guess this is the type of fun we have to look forward to in the states... :-(

Comment: The pricing for the new FTTP services they're rolling out contry-wide over the next 10 years have just been released as well. Anyone feel like paying [$140/month for their internet](http://www.internode.on.net/residential/fibre_to_the_home/nbn_plans/)? Thought not.

Comment: I would gladly pay $140 for a 100/40 connection...if only it weren't for that pesky 200GB quota...Netflix alone would bankrupt me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out the event log was filled with hundreds of SQL Server Reporting errors about invalid credentials and bad linked servers. I went through every troubleshooting step on several MSDN articles to reset permissions, reset passwords, match GUIDs for reporting services, and nothing fixed it.

I ended up having to export all the TMG firewall rules and restore a backup from a few weeks ago. It all works OK now, but obviously all the logs are gone. No idea what caused it.